# How to delete the matching pattern from given occurrence

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, awk

I'm trying to delete matching patterns, starting from the second occurrence, using `sed` or `awk`. The input file contains the information below:

```
abc
def
abc
ghi
jkl
abc
xyz
abc
```

I want to the delete the pattern `abc` from the second instance. The output should be as below:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
xyz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neat `sed` solution:

```
sed '/abc/{2,$d}' test.txt
abc
def
ghi
jkl
xyz
```

Comment: This won't work if the first `abc` pattern were to happen on 2nd line or later. This command just ignores the first line.. parses from the 2nd line till the last: `2,$`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '$0=="abc"{c[$0]++} c[$0]<2; ' file
abc
def
ghi
jkl
xyz
```

Just change the "2" to "3" or whatever number you want to keep the first N occurrences instead of just the first 1.

Answer (score 2):

One way using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'f&&$0==p{next}$0==p{f=1}1' p="abc" file
abc
def
ghi
jkl
xyz
```

Just set `p` to pattern that you only want the first instance of printing:

Answer (score 1):

Taken from : [unix.com](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/153131-remove-duplicate-lines-using-awk.html)

Using `awk '!x[$0]++'` will remove duplicate lines. x is a array and it's initialized to 0.the index of x is $0,if $0 is first time meet,then plus 1 to the value of x[$0],x[$0] now is 1.As ++ here is "suffix ++",0 is returned and then be added.So !x[$0] is true,the $0 is printed by default.if $0 appears more than once,! x[$0] will be false so won't print $0.

Comment: This will also remove any duplicates of any other patterns. I think the OP just want the duplicates of a given pattern removing.