# How to prevent sed from editing the line containing the first match of a pattern, when a variable is used?

Tags: bash, sed

This `sed` code deletes all lines containing `{$line}` found withing `file.txt`:

```
sed -i "/{$pattern}/d" ./file.txt
```

Currently, this deletes all of the lines in this sample `file.txt` when `$pattern` is set to "cat":

```
One day, the {cat} said to the {owl}, "What are you eating for breakfast, {owl}?"
The {owl} replied, "I am eating {cereal}. Would you like some, {cat}?"
"Yes, I would," replied the {cat}.
So the {cat} and the {owl} ate {cereal}.
```

I need to change this, such that it does not delete the first found line containing `{$pattern}`, but only deletes all subsequent appearances found in later lines:

E.g., suppose `file.txt` is this:

```
One day, the {cat} said to the {owl}, "What are you eating for breakfast, {owl}?"
The {owl} replied, "I am eating {cereal}. Would you like some, {cat}?"
"Yes, I would," replied the {cat}.
So the {cat} and the {owl} ate {cereal}.
```

If `$pattern` were set to "cat", the output would look like this, because line 1 has the first occurrence of "cat", and all other later lines also have it, so they are all deleted:

```
One day, the {cat} said to the {owl}, "What are you eating for breakfast, {owl}?"
```

If `$pattern` were set to "owl", the output would look like this, because line 1 contains the first occurrence of "owl", and lines 2 and 4 also have instances, which are deleted:

```
One day, the {cat} said to the {owl}, "What are you eating for breakfast, {owl}?"
"Yes, I would," replied the {cat}.
```

If `$pattern` were set to "cereal", the output would look like this with line 4 deleted, because line 4 is the only one with an additional occurrence of "cereal".

```
One day, the {cat} said to the {owl}, "What are you eating for breakfast, {owl}?"
The {owl} replied, "I am eating {cereal}. Would you like some, {cat}?"
"Yes, I would," replied the {cat}.
```

- The file must not be sorted, as the order of lines is important.
- Note that line 1 contains two copies of "owl", but the second appearance on that line is not regarded as the second appearance of "owl".

Is there any way to set `sed` to not delete the line containing the first appearance of `{$patter}`, but to only edit all later occurrences of a pattern?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910718/how-to-delete-the-matching-pattern-from-given-occurrence

Comment: Yes, that nearly answers, but I find `sed -i "/$line/{2,$d}"` results in `sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unexpected ','`. `{2,$d}` seems incompatible with double-quotes on `sed`, but `$line` does not seem to work when single-quotes are used.

Comment: you want to delete each line of text that content $line in it or every occurence of $line in the file (in both case, since 2nd occurence). Your question state the content but the sample  state the full line and reply goes that way ?

Comment: If "$line" contained the text ".*", what would you want to happen? What if "$line" was set to "her" and you hit a line that contained "there" - is that a matching line or not? Do you want to delete the lines that contain the pattern or onlythe lines that exactly match the pattern or do you want to delete from the pattern to the end of of the line or something else? Please post some representative sample input and expected output showing these and other edge cases that you will care about.

Comment: If "$line" is set to "her", this would only match items marked as "{her}", not anything like "there", or "{there}", but "t{her}e" would be regarded as a match. Note that "{" and "}" are marks I've placed in the text previously to make it easier for this script to find only the correct items and to ignore other text. In other words, it does not need to know what a word boundary is.

Comment: It should never do anything to the line containing the first occurrence, even if the second occurrence of the matching pattern is in that same first line. It should only delete those later lines also having appearances.

Comment: ".*" does not appear anywhere in my input file, and I don't know which choice is best or what kind of answer would benefit others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative using awk:

```
$ awk "/$line/&&c++ {next} 1" ./file.txt
```

Comment: You should use variable with `awk` like this: `awk -v var="$line" '$0~var&&c++ {next} 1' ./file.txt`

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{'"$var"'}/{x;//{x;d};x;h}' file
```

Use `$var` as switch held in the hold space.

Answer (score 2):

I should have tested this more. potong pointed out correctly in the comments that

> This will skip over every $line and delete everything else.

---

According to http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35a, you could do:

```
sed -i '
    /{$line}/,$ {
        /{$line}/n # skip over the line that has "{$line}" on it
        d
    }
' ./file.txt
```

Comment: This will skip over every $line and delete everything else.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `$d`, otherwise it gets treated as a shell variable and expanded by the shell (possibly to an empty string):

```
sed -i "/{$line}/{2,\$d}" ./file.txt
```

Comment: I tried running this, but found it seems to be ignoring the `{` and `}` and just erasing any lines with `$line`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -ne "/$line/{2,\$p}" -e "/$line/! {p}" file
```

Comment: I don't think this does what you think it does. To me it says `if a line contains $line and is between 2 and the end-of-file, print it. Otherwise if it does not contain $line print it.` The OP wants the first occurence of $line printed and the rest supressed.