# Sed/Awk to delete second occurence of string - platform independent

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm looking for a line in bash that would work on both linux as well as OS X to remove the second line containing the desired string:

```
Header
1
2
...
Header
10
11
...
```

Should become

```
Header
1
2
...
10
11
...
```

My first attempt was using the deletion option of sed:

```
sed -i '/^Header.*/d' file.txt
```

But well, that removes the first occurence as well.

[How to delete the matching pattern from given occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910718/how-to-delete-the-matching-pattern-from-given-occurrence) suggests to use something like this:

```
sed -i '/^Header.*/{2,$d} file.txt
```

But on OS X that gives the error

```
sed: 1: "/^Header.*/{2,$d}": extra characters at the end of d command
```

Next, i tried substitution, where I know how to use `2,$`, and subsequent empty line deletion:

```
sed -i '2,$s/^Header.*//' file.txt
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' file.txt
```

This works on Linux, but on OS X, as mentioned here [sed command with -i option failing on Mac, but works on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247068/sed-command-failing-on-mac-but-works-on-linux) , you'd have to use

```
sed -i '' '2,$s/^Header.*//' file.txt
sed -i '' '/^\s*$/d' file.txt
```

And this one in return doesn't work on Linux.

My question then, isn't there a simple way to make this work in any Bash? Doesn't have to be sed, but should be as shell independent as possible and i need to modify the file itself.

Comment: I suggest perl for this.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is file-dependent and not line-dependent, `awk` can be a better tool.

Just keep a counter on how many times this happened:

```
awk -v patt="Header" '$0 == patt && ++f==2 {next} 1' file
```

This skips the line that matches exactly the given pattern and does it for the second time. On the rest of lines, it prints normally.

Comment: It doesn't work when useing patt="Header.*" and also it goes to stdout, while I need to modify the file itself. How would it have to be modified to achieve this?

Comment: Hardcode then `/Header.*/`. To do in place editing, `awk ... file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file`

Comment: @Max Adding `.*` to a regexp comparison is useless as it matches zero or more occurrences of any character so it will match exactly the same lines as just `Header` alone. In this case it MAY be overkill but if you like it you could keep the variable and just change `==` to `~` to do a regexp instead of string comparison to find `Header` in a line as opposed to when it's the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using awk for this:

```
awk '!/^Header/ || !f++' file
```

This prints all lines that don't start with "Header". Short-circuit evaluation means that if the left hand side of the `||` is true, the right hand side isn't evaluated. If the line does start with Header, the second part `!f++` is only true once.

```
$ cat file
baseball
Header and some other stuff
aardvark
Header for the second time and some other stuff
orange
$ awk '!/^Header/ || !f++' file
baseball
Header and some other stuff
aardvark
orange
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1b;/^Header/d' file
```

Ignore the first line and then remove any occurrence of a line beginning with `Header`.

To remove subsequent occurrences of the first line regardless of the string, use:

```
sed -ri '1h;1b;G;/^(.*)\n\1$/!P;d' file
```